# Control flow of messages in Akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, message-queue, actor, future

I have an actor using Akka which performs an action that takes some time to complete, because it has to download a file from the network.

```
  def receive = {
    case songId: String => {
      Future {
        val futureFile = downloadFile(songId)

        for (file <- futureFile) {
          val fileName = doSomenthingWith(file)
          otherActor ! fileName
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I would like to control the flow of messages to this actor. If I try to download too many files simultaneously, I have a network bottleneck. The problem is that I am using a Future inside the actor receive, so, the methods exits and the actor is ready to process a new message. If I remove the Future, I will download only one file per time.

What is the best way to limit the number of messages being processed per unit of time? Is there a better way to design this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a contrib implementation of message Throttling, as [described here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.0/index.html#akka.contrib.throttle.TimerBasedThrottler).

The code is very simple:

```
// A simple actor that prints whatever it receives
class Printer extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case x => println(x)
  }
}

val printer = system.actorOf(Props[Printer], "printer")

// The throttler for this example, setting the rate
val throttler = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[TimerBasedThrottler], 3 msgsPer 1.second))

// Set the target
throttler ! SetTarget(Some(printer))
// These three messages will be sent to the printer immediately
throttler ! "1"
throttler ! "2"
throttler ! "3"
// These two will wait at least until 1 second has passed
throttler ! "4"
throttler ! "5"
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a contrib project for Akka that provides a throttle implementation (http://letitcrash.com/post/28901663062/throttling-messages-in-akka-2).  If you sit this in front of the actual download actor then you can effectively throttle the rate of messages going into that actor.  It's not 100% perfect in that if the download times are taking longer than expected you could still end up with more downloads then might be desired, but it's a pretty simple implementation and we use it quite a bit to great effect.

Another option could be to [use a pool](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html#Pool) of download actors and remove the future and allow the actors to perform this blocking so that they are truly handling only one message at a time.  Because you are going to let them block, I would suggest [giving them their own `Dispatcher` (`ExecutionContext`)](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html) so that this blocking does not negatively effect the main Akka `Dispatcher`.  If you do this, then the pool size itself represents your max allowed number of simultaneous downloads.

Both of these solutions are pretty much "out-of-the-box" solutions that don't require much custom logic to support your use case.

**Edit**

I also thought it would be good to mention the [Work Pulling Pattern](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern/) as well.  With this approach you could still use a pool and then a single work distributer in front.  Each worker (download actor) could perform the download (still using a `Future`) and only request new work (pull) from the work distributer when that `Future` has fully completed meaning the download is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an upper bound on the amount of simultanious downloads you want to happen you can 'ack' back to the actor saying that a download completed and to free up a spot to download another file:

```
case object AckFileRequest

class ActorExample(otherActor:ActorRef, maxFileRequests:Int = 1) extends Actor {

  var fileRequests = 0

  def receive = {
    case songId: String if fileRequests < maxFileRequests =>
      fileRequests += 1
      val thisActor = self
      Future {
        val futureFile = downloadFile(songId)
        //not sure if you're returning the downloaded file or a future here, 
        //but you can move this to wherever the downloaded file is and ack
        thisActor ! AckFileRequest

        for (file <- futureFile) {
          val fileName = doSomenthingWith(file)
          otherActor ! fileName
        }
      }
    case songId: String =>
      //Do some throttling here
      val thisActor = self
      context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1 second, thisActor, songId)
    case AckFileRequest => fileRequests -= 1
  }
}
```

In this example, if there are too many file requests then we put this `songId` request on hold and queue it back up for processing 1 second later. You can obviously change this however you see fit, maybe you can just send the message straight back to the actor in a tight loop or do some other throttling, depends on your use case.

Comment: @DanielCukier no they are not, however the actor is guaranteed to be single threaded so you shouldn't need to worry about thread safety inside of the actor context.

Comment: The solution you gave me looks fine, but I was thinking if there isn't any built in feature in Akka that does something similar, so I don't have to control these things manually...

Comment: @DanielCukier My only other thought is that you control the thread pool used by the futures to download files. So if you wanted max 8 downloads at a time you use a threadpool of size 8 and let the futures queue up to be processed by the pool.